# rc.status equivalent in Redhat

Tags: rhel, suse

I need to have `rc.status` file in RedHat Linux, to install one software(java app). Is there any way to enable it on RedHat? Or is there an equivalent on RedHat?

Comment: Start by telling us what `rc.status` does?

Comment: rc.status is a default setting on Suse which controls start stop process

Answer (score 1):

The command is `service`, i.e `service --status-all` would list status of all services.